# Изменение записей БД используя ajax

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Добрый день! У меня возникла проблема с отсутствием обновления страницы после операции множественного изменения записей.

Вообщем имеется таблица article с полями:

- `article_id integer not null auto_increment primary key`;
- `article_title varchar(300)`;

И имеются два файла:

- index.php в котором есть вывод данных из таблицы и скрипт ajax по поводу передачи данных на изменение выделенных записей.
- updateArticle.php - файл в котором идет изменения записи;

Вот скрин того как выделенные записи переходят в режим редактирования (превращаются из текста в поля input для последующего изменения значений и занесения в БД):
[image]

Вот код функции который отвечает за изменение записей в цикле:

```
// обрабатываем событие нажатия на кнопку "Изменить выделенные товары"   
     $('input[name=editArticle]').click( 
       function () 
       {
          var checkElements=document.getElementsByName("check_button");
          for(var i=0; i<checkElements.length; i++)
          {
            checkElement = checkElements[i];
            if (checkElement.checked==1)
            {
               // отправляем AJAX запрос
               $.ajax(
               {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "updateArticle.php",
                 data: {article_id:checkElement.value, article_title:document.getElementsByName("edit_title["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].value},
                 success: function() 
                 { 

                 }

                }
             );  
            }

          }
          location.reload();            
       }
     );
```

Поясню **editArticle** это название кнопки которая осуществляет редактирование. **check_button** - это флажки, которые стоят справа в таблице. Строка `article_title:document.getElementsByName("edit_title["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].value` означает, что POST-переменной `article_title` присваивается значение поля из input с именем `edit_title[xxx]`.

В файле updateArticle.php такой код:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$article_id = $_POST['article_id'];
$article_title = $_POST['article_title'];

$connect->query("update article set
 article_title = '$article_title'
 where
 article_id = '$article_id'");
?>
```

В итоге операция изменения происходит успешно, в базу данных вносятся все изменения. Но при этом не отображается моментально на странице, только после обновления страницы все значения появляются. В чем тут ошибка? Пробовал играть с `location.reload()` переносить его в цикл и в конструкцию success, не помогало обновлялась только одна запись, остальные только после ручного обновления страницы.

Comment: `*оффтоп*` - Вам надо не в цикле посылать запросы, а собрать сначала все данные, упаковать их в массивы и один разом всё отправить.

Comment: Это хотите сказать что потом будет передаваться куча POST Переменных, если через массив загрузить их в обработчик Ajax? Как же разбирать массив потом, чтобы выбрать article_id и article_title для каждой записи?

Comment: @IntegralAL - а вы отправьте массив объектов, и перебирайте объекты уже на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 2):

1) Глупо, очень глупо делать цикл ajax запросов, составьте массив данных и передайте их php как json, там его распакуйте и корректно занесите.

2) location.reload перезагрузит страничку, какой в этом смысл? Просто после изменение названия, инпут обратно в "текст". Зачем извращаться?

Comment: У меня просто компоненты input представляют собой массив вида edit_title[xxx] и массив идентификаторов и чтобы без присвоения в дополнительный массив я сразу отправляю запросы. Я плохо знаю ajax потому прошу разьяснить, как это будет выглядеть... А location.reload использую для того чтобы обновить измененные записи. Данные берутся из таблицы, а не из input'ов напрямую.

Comment: json! я же написал

Comment: Я не знаю что такое json. Буквально вчера начал ajax изучать.

Comment: Что бы не дробить элементы на два массива, упакуйте их в объекты.

`arr_id[n] = checkElement.value;
 arr_title[n] = document.getElementsByName("edit_title["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].value;
 n++;`
заменить на 
`obj = {id: checkElement.value, title: document.getElementsByName("edit_title["+checkElement.value+"]")[0].value};

arr[n++] = obj;`